# Content migration in Drupal

Tags: drupal, migration, feed

I'm in the need to move content between several drupal environments (i.e. development -> review -> production) each environment is an exact replication of drupal (except for the content, of course).

Whats the best way to accomplish this?

I'm thinking of views and feeds (using views to create a feed in one environment and consume that feed in the next environment with feeds node importers). Will that work with translations? Because I have one node translated in several languages.

Please Advice
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the transport module:
http://drupal.org/project/transport

Comment: Also http://drupal.org/project/content_push is a module which depends on transport, the blurb sounds like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The Feeds module is good for importing nodes from CSV files (where you would be mapping columns in the file to fields in the content types). But because you are just replicating nodes in similar environments, the Node export module will be easier to use. You can use the Views Bulk Operations module to allow you to choose multiple nodes to export right from the Admin > Content Management > Content node list.

Install the two modules (Views Bulk Operations depends on Views, so you'll need it as well) in both of the Drupal installations. Make certain that the content types are identical (i.e. same machine names, same CCK fields, etc), then go to the Admin > Content Mgmt > Content list and filter the content items to the ones that you want to export. Check the checkbox at the top of the list to select all of the visible nodes, and then choose "Export nodes" from the dropdown selector just above that in the Update options section. Click update and you'll be presented with a dialog box called "Node Code" with an array with all of the node details in it. Copy the array to your clipboard (and save it in a text file if you are not currently connected to the other Drupal installation).

In the second Drupal installation, choose "Node Export: Import" from the Content Management section of the Admin area, and either paste the text in the "Paste code" section or choose the saved text file in the "Upload file" section and click Import to bring in the node content.

Comment: The node export is great but it has problem with translations nodes. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you're moving 100% of the content and want an *exact* replication, you might prefer to just migrate the content-related database tables using the Backup/Migrate module, the MySQL command-line utilities or phpMyAdmin. This will ensure that things like node IDs and author UIDs are preserved.

I've worked on a large i18n project where nodes were exported using Views Bonus Pack XML output then imported using a Feeds XML import. It's do-able, but be prepared for some hand-tweaking to get it to work correctly.

There's also the deploy module (http://drupal.org/project/deploy) that lets content managers transmit nodes between environments from the Drupal admin interface in a batch.

Comment: I'll give a try to the deploy module. Did you find any drawbacks  using it?